# What are the advantages/use cases of optional patterns introduced in swift 2?

Tags: swift, swift2, switch-statement, pattern-matching, option-type

For the simple cases like `if let` or `guard` I don't see the advantage,

```
if case let x? = someOptional where ... {
  ...
}

//I don't see the advantage over the original if let

if let x = someOptional where ... {
  ...
}
```

For the `for-case-let` case to simplify working with optional collections, I really hope swift can go one step further:

```
for case let x? in optionalArray {
  ...
}

//Wouldn't it be better if we could just write

for let x? in optionalArray {
  ...
}
```

After google it for a while the only case I find useful is this "[Swift 2 Pattern Matching: Unwrapping Multiple Optionals](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-pattern-matching-unwrapping-multiple-optionals/)" :

```
switch (username, password) {
case let (username?, password?):
    print("Success!")
case let (username?, nil):
    print("Password is missing")
...
```

So any other advantages of introducing optional patterns?

Comment: In my observation, this ' if case', or 'while case' , or 'for case' are handy constructs if you want to check the value of an enum without a full blown switch - case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're conflating two different concepts. Admittedly, the syntax isn't immediately intuitive, but I hope their uses are clarified below.
(I recommend reading the page about [Patterns in *The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html).)

## `case` conditions

The "case condition" refers to the ability to write:

- `if case «pattern» = «expr» { ... }`
- `while case «pattern» = «expr» { ... }`
- `for case «pattern» in «expr» { ... }`

These are particularly useful because they let you extract enum values **without using `switch`**.

Your example, `if case let x? = someOptional ...`, is a valid example of this, however I believe it's most useful for **enums besides Optional**.

```
enum MyEnum {
    case A
    case B(Int)
    case C(String)
}

func extractStringsFrom(values: [MyEnum]) -> String {
    var result = ""

    // Without case conditions, we have to use a switch
    for value in values {
        switch value {
        case let .C(str):
            result += str
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    // With a case condition, it's much simpler:
    for case let .C(str) in values {
        result += str
    }

    return result
}
```

You can actually use case conditions with pretty much any pattern that you might normally use in a `switch`. It can be weird sometimes:

- `if case let str as String = value { ... }` (equivalent to `if let str = value as? String`)
- `if case is String = value { ... }` (equivalent to `if value is String`)
- `if case 1...3 = value { ... }` (equivalent to `if (1...3).contains(value)` or `if 1...3 ~= value`)

## The optional pattern, a.k.a. `let x?`

The optional pattern, on the other hand, is a pattern that lets you unwrap optionals in contexts besides a simple `if let`. It's particularly useful when used **in a `switch`** (similar to your username/password example):

```
func doSomething(value: Int?) {
    switch value {
    //case 2:  // Not allowed
    case 2?:
        print("found two")

    case nil:
        print("found nil")

    case let x:
        print("found a different number: \(x)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better than apple document! Thanks.

Comment: Good answer. However, one weird thing is that `case 2` which you commented out as not allowed in your last example, actually works. Seems the compiler is doing some upcasting behind the scenes.